# How to create a variable for the number of candidates the user inputs

Tags: c

I need to tally the number of votes for the candidates and display them, but there is not a set number of candidates, the user inputs it. How would you go about making a variable for each candidate with a loop or something similar. This is what I have so far. I am thinking that I might have to make another array but I am not sure how that would work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
//2d array that will hold the names of the candidates
    char cand[100][1000];
//The following could has the user enter the the names of the
//candidates. It places a \0 character at the end of each name
    printf("How many candidates are in the race? ");
//Holds the number of candidates in the race
    int numCand;
    scanf("%i",&numCand);
//get rid of the return from the scanf above
    getchar();
//Get the names of the candidates
    int row = 0;
//one name per row and go until we have the number of candidates
    while(row < numCand)
    {
        printf("Please enter the name candidate number %i: ",row+1);
//get the first character of the name
        char cur = getchar();
        int col = 0;
//while they haven't hit enter get the next character
        while(cur != '\n')
        {
            cand[row][col] = cur;
            cur = getchar();
            col = col +1;
        }
//add the \0 character at the end of the useful info in the array
        cand[row][col]='\0';
        row = row + 1;
    }
//Finally ask them how many people will be voting
    printf("How many people will be voting? ");
    int numVoters;
    scanf("%i",&numVoters);
    printf("\n**********VOTING WILL COMMENCE NOW***********\n");
    /*YOU WORK GOES BELOW HERE*/
    int i;
    i = 0;
    int j;
    j = 0;
    int k;
    k=1;
    int l;
    l =1;
    int v;
    v = 0;
    int vote[numCand];

    while (i < numVoters)
    {
        i = i+1;
        printf("Hello voter %i the candidates are: \n", i);
        while (j < numCand)
        {

            printf("\t Candidate number %i is \n\t %s \n", k, cand[j]);
            int cand[j];
            cand[j] = l;
            l=l+1;
            k=k+1;
            j=j+1;
        }
        j=0;
        k=1;
        printf("Who would you like to vote for? (enter candidate number) ");
        scanf("%i", &vote[v] );
        v = v+1;

    }
    i = 0;
    while(i < numVoters)
    {

    i = i+1;
    }
printf("The results are:\n");


}
```

Comment: You seem to know how to use arrays, so what's the confusion here?  Make an appropriately sized array for however many candidates you need to deal with.

Comment: Have you come across dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` et al?  That's an obvious way to deal with the problem.

Comment: I think you are using `char cand[100][1000];` for storing candidate info and `int vote[numCand];` for storing the number of votes per candidate, if that's the case then instead of using `scanf("%i", &vote[v] );` declare a variable to read the candidate num like `int cand_num;` and use `scanf("%i", &cand_num );` and increment that candidate votes `vote[cand_num]++` after everything is done use `for(int c =0; c<numCand;c++) printf("Cand =%s, votes=%d\n",cand[c],vote[c]);` dont forget to make sure `vote` array all zero before using

Answer (score 0):

That seems a too big program for small problem consider using `struct` , it will be easy to handle the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define BUFFER 50
#define MAX_VOTES 1000
#define NUM_OF_CANDIDATES 50

struct Candidate 
{
    char Name[BUFFER];
    int Id;
    int Votes;
};

void ReadCandidateInfo(struct Candidate *Cand, unsigned int num_cand);
void StartVoting(struct Candidate *Cand, unsigned int num_cand);
void AnnounanceResult(struct Candidate *Cand, unsigned int num_cand);

void ReadCandidateInfo(struct Candidate *Cand, unsigned int num_cand)
{

    
}

void StartVoting(struct Candidate *Cand, unsigned int num_cand)
{
    
}

void AnnounanceResult(struct Candidate *Cand, unsigned int num_cand)
{
    
}

int main() 
{
   struct Candidate Cand[NUM_OF_CANDIDATES];
   // Read Name and Id and set Votes to 0 first
   ReadCandidateInfo(Cand,sizeof(Cand)/sizeof(Cand[0]));
   // take input for voting for candiates based on Id or Name
   StartVoting(Cand,sizeof(Cand)/sizeof(Cand[0]));
   // Finally Announce the Result
   AnnounanceResult(Cand,sizeof(Cand)/sizeof(Cand[0]));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have just re-designed the entire program without explaining what this person should do, or why.  As such, this looks like a code-only answer.  But in fact, it also doesn't answer the question.  So it's basically a comment.

Comment: @paddy my answer is kind of a suggestion to make the program better and my intention is to let him know importance of structured and readable code, he could reorganize the code once the error is corrected.

Comment: @IrAM - your suggestions are constructive, and your response (emphasizing code examples, rather than "explaining stuff") might be exactly what the OP needs.  Thank you for contributing :)